# SQLException Occurred

Tags: c#, c++, sql

Can someone explain what is wrong with my program?
Just wanted to make a simple login program as I am a beginner but stuck on this error.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Umer\Documents\Data.mdf;Integra‌​ted Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count (*) From dbo.Table where Username='" + textBox1.Text + "'and password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

The problem is in `sda.Fill(dt);`.  It says:

> SqlException occurred Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

It says SqlException occurred Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table' 
This is the picture of my code. Hope i will will get the answer. Thanks

Comment: You should post text, not the picture. Also, concrete your problem. "Code does not work" is not too concrete.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone to help you based upon the information you provided (or lack thereof).  Post your code, tell us what is happening, tell us what you expect to happen, and include any environmental variables that you think might be important.

Comment: problem is in sda.Fill(dt);

Comment: It says SqlException occurred 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Comment: @UmerKhalid I updated the question with the information you added in comments... in the future you should put all relevant info into the question itself.

Comment: Thanks buddy its my first time here I posted my first question did'nt know how to write it . I will be careful next time.

Comment: Look inside the exception, it should display somewhere the exact query that tries to execute. Post it here.

Comment: Use `ExecuteScalar` to return single values. Why do you need all the overhead of adapter and `DataTable`????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you have the correct Table in your sql database you are referencing.
The Table name is "Table" and it has two columns "Username" and "Password"

Comments

1. Your Sql statment is going to return the number of rows that have the username and password that match.
2. Passing parameters like that is dangerous and subject to hidden sql utilize the sqlParameter class
3. You should break out parameters and such for ease of reading.

   ```
   String ConnectionString = @"DataSource=LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Umer\Documents\Data.mdf;Integra‌​ted Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
   String QueryString = @"Select Count (*) From dbo.Table where Username= @Username and Password = @Password";

    SqlParameter[] Parameters = {new SqlParameter("Username",textBox1.text)
                                ,new SqlParameter("Password",textBox2.text)};


    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(QueryString, sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

    int nCount;
    if (int.TryParse(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out nCount))
    {
        //nCount has valid value
    }
    else
    {
        //nCount has invalid value
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There is missing space between the single cuote and the 'and' keyword

... textBox1.Text + "'and ...

BTW, to avoid SQL injection (and application errors in passwords containing quotes) you should also use parameters as Mike Schmidt suggested.